# Pandas_Unable to write all the rows into the excel sheet

Tags: python, pandas, jira

I'm trying to export all the defects from JIRA into Excel sheet by writing a Python script using Pandas.
I'm able to capture all the information into the Pandas Data frame. When i print it on console, i'm able to see multiple rows in the data frame. But when it is exported to "output.xlsx" excel sheet, only one row is getting added into excel sheet. Please let me know where i'm going wrong in the below code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
from jira import JIRA

allissues = []
options = {'server': 'Server url'}
jira = JIRA(options, basic_auth=('username', 'password'))

df = pd.DataFrame()
i=0
issues = jira.search_issues('search condition',maxResults=70)

for i in issues:
    d = {
    'Issue id': i.id,
    'creator' : i.fields.creator,
    'resolution': i.fields.resolution,
    'status.name': i.fields.status.name,
    'versions': i.fields.versions,
            }

    allissues = pd.DataFrame(d)
    print(allissues)
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')
    allissues.to_excel(writer)
    writer.save()
print('DataFrame is written successfully to Excel File.')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your jira code is correct, could you give this a shot?

```py
import pandas as pd
from jira import JIRA

allissues = []
options = {'server': 'Server url'}
jira = JIRA(options, basic_auth=('username', 'password'))

issues = jira.search_issues('search condition',maxResults=70)

for i in issues:
    d = {
    'Issue id': i.id,
    'creator' : i.fields.creator,
    'resolution': i.fields.resolution,
    'status.name': i.fields.status.name,
    'versions': i.fields.versions,
            }
    allissues.append(d)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')
df = pd.DataFrame(all_issues)
df.to_excel(writer, index=False)
writer.save()
print('DataFrame is written successfully to Excel File.')
```

Comment: Thanks a ton Balaji. That worked very well !!. I had tried append() method as well. But probably didn't use it in the right manner. Thanks again.